# User input list values in python 3.4

Tags: python-3.x, list, user-input

This code works but it's not what I need

```
lst = range(1,17)
```

It uses from 1 to 16 to do some calculations but in fact I want to specify the values, when I type them inside the code it works:

```
lst = (14, 1, 6, 8)
```

but what I want is the user who must choose which values to be in the list by inputting them

I have tried this but it does not works

```
lst = (a1, a2, a3)
a1 = int(input("number 1: "))
a2 = int(input("number 2: "))
a3 = int(input("number 3: "))
```

Comment: I can guess as to how your code doesn't work, but you need to be **explicit** about what happens instead, and what you expected to happen. Don't just state that something doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You have to switch the order of your lines of code:

```
a1 = int(input("number 1: "))
a2 = int(input("number 2: "))
a3 = int(input("number 3: "))
lst = (a1, a2, a3)
```

Python will execute your example code line-by-line in top-down order, so if you want to create list/tuple from inputed values the creation has to be as last one.